# Connecting mysql and tomcat?

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ubuntu

Hi I am new to tomcat and mysql.

I have installed Tomcat and mysql in Ubuntu 9.10 and both are working great!!

But now I have task of connecting mysql and tomcat.
I dont have any idea on this. However I looked some manuals but did not find any luck.

Guy, Please give me the step by step procedure on how to connect mysql with tomcat.

btw I have downloaded mysql connector and copied the .jar file to $CATALINA_HOME/lib

What else should I do ?
Thanks!

@at0mzk
This is the steps I followed to install tomcat  http://www.linuxnix.com/2010/12/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-linuxredhatubuntu.html     and I installed mysql server and client using the commands sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client   later I downloaded JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J)  from http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/  and extrated it and pasted the .jar file  in /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/lib ( I dont have $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib) . My questions are  1) Is the connection between tomcat and sql established ?  2) do i need to install mysql-server when I have tomcat server ?

Answer (score 0):

Which manual did you follow when installing? Should follow installation intructions in the Tomcat manual for your version. For example 5.5:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example

note that manual says $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib, not $CATALINA_HOME/lib

Comment: This is the steps I followed to install tomcat http://www.linuxnix.com/2010/12/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-on-linuxredhatubuntu.html and I installed mysql server and client using the commands sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client later I downloaded JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J) from http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/ and extrated it and pasted the .jar file in /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/lib ( I dont have $CATALINA_HOME/common/lib) . My questions are 1) Is the connection between tomcat and sql established ? 2) do i need to install mysql-server when I have tomcat server ?

Answer (score 0):

> "do i need to install mysql-server when I have tomcat server"

Firstly, do you need mysql at all? I have plenty of web apps that use alternative databases, even embedded ones. Mysql is not required to run Tomcat.

> "Is the connection between tomcat and sql established"

Secondly, individual web applications can themselves establish a connection to mysql directly.

I don't know much about the process of setting up a Tomcat JNDI data source as *at0mzk* has pointed out, as I've never done it, but I suspect it is again up to the individual application to seek out that service and connect to the database using it. I *can* say that you don't necessarily need it though, depending on what your applications' require.